# ZendFramework: Change Form Element View Helper InputErrorClass to 'has-error'

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use the FormRow View Helper in my forms which works fine except for the fact that, when the element has errors, it adds 'input-error' to the  class.

Since I am using Bootstrap3, I would like to use the 'has-error' class for the input element.

Is there a easy way to set the default InputErrorClass to 'has-error' without creating my own plugins that would extend ForRow or FormInput?

The Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRow class has a public function (setInputErrorClass) that sets the inputErrorClass property but I can't seem to be able to use it since FormRow is a plugin, unless I am missing something about ZF and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using in your view:

```
$this->formRow($element);
```

You can add before you use formRow:

```
$this->formRow()->setInputErrorClass('has-error');
```

or

```
$this->formRow()->setInputErrorClass('has-error')->render($element);
```

Comment: Yes I do.  But I also realize that my question is not quite right to start with.  As per Bootstrap, I need to add `.has-error` to `<div class="form-group">` and not to the `<input>` element, and only when my element has error messages.  I will update my question.  I also ended up developing a formgroup plugin that provides the `<div class="form-group"> markup using formrow internally.  I will share that too.

Comment: Looking at your answer, it does answer my question about how to set the inputErrorClass.  Thanks.  I'll mark it as answered.